# Como puedo encontrar los numeros repetidos en una lista y sumarlos

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for

estoy recién empezando en Python y tengo una duda, una duda que no pude encontrar en ningun lugar o es que no supe como buscar-la.
La pregunta es, como podría encontrar los números repetidos en una lista y sumarlos, hasta ahora he intentado con un "for", para así poder recorrer la lista.
pondré un ejemplo.

```
def ejemplo():
    diction = (3,2,3,4,5)
    for i in diction:
        if i = i + 1
           return sum
```

Este sería un ejemplo de lo que quiero decir, no sé si me explique bien, pero el código en sí está "MAL", hice el código para que cojan una idea de lo que estoy diciendo, llevo bastante tiempo pensando y no tuve más elección que preguntar aquí, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperas con [2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5]?

Comment: El resultado que espero es la suma de 3+3

Comment: pero para eso tiene que recorrer todo la lista y no se como hacer-lo

Comment: recorrer para ver cuantos numeros repetidos hay no?

Comment: Pero el 2 también está repetido. ¿Por qué ignorarlo?

Comment: en la lista solo esta repetido el 3, el 2 solo esta repetido 1 vez el 4 una vez y el 5 1 vez

Comment: El ejemplo de arriba está inventado, solo lo digo por si acaso xd

Comment: *pero para eso tiene que recorrer todo la lista y no se como hacer-lo* ... bueno, en verdad eso ya lo has hecho -> `for i in diction:` esto basicamente está recorriendo los números, así que te propongo que primero lo intentes hacer así a tu manera, puesto que viendo el código que has puesto, me da la sensación de que no has intentado hacer nada y aquí estamos para solucionar errores... ese código no tiene un error, pues no es ni siquiera válido tal como tú has dicho (*pero el código en sí está "MAL"*). Te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para entender cómo funciona SO.

Comment: Llevo 2 h intentando encontrar como solucionar el tema, "como podría encontrar los números repetidos en una lista y sumarlos" esta es mi duda, y si recorrí la lista y no me di cuenta como dije estoy recién empezando en Python, no lo voy a conocer todo,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear una array `counter`donde almacenarías el contador de veces que aparece el numero. Donde el indice es el numero y su contenido el contador. De ahí validas que números aparecieron 2 veces es decir `counter[i]>1` y los agregas a un diccionario para mostrarlo como respuesta, sumando las veces que apareció el numero (`i * counter [i]`) .

```
def ejemplo():
    diction = [3,2,3,4,5]
    maxInt = max(diction)
    counter = [0] * (maxInt+1)
    for i in diction:
        counter[i] += 1
    
    result = {}
    for i in range(maxInt):
        if(counter[i]>1):
            result[i] = i * counter [i]
    
    return result

print ( ejemplo() )
```

Comment: Muy Buena explicación, lo pondré en práctica para que me quede más claro.

Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema se puede resumir a dos subproblemas.

1. Encontrar los valores repetidos en un iterable, en este caso, una lista.
2. Sumar una lista de valores. Los valores son los que anteriormente capturaste.

**Solución a problema 1.**

```py
from collections import Counter

lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2]
contador = Counter(lista)
```

El código anterior hace uso de la clase `Counter` encargada de tomar un iterable en su constructor y que permite saber que elementos únicos existen en ese iterable y cuantas veces se repiten. La clase contador implementa cierto protocolo que le permite comportarse como si fuera un diccionario donde la llave hace referencia a un elemento y su valor es el número de apariciones de dicho elemento en el iterable que se paso en el constructor. Lo anterior se puede visualizar con:

```
contador[1] # Retorna 1, solo se repite una vez el elemento 1 en la lista
contador[2] # Retorna 2, se repite dos veces el elemento 2 en la lista
```

Ahora la pregunta es ¿Cómo filtro a los elementos para quedarme con los que se repiten?. La respuesta corta es:

```py
repetidos = [elemento*contador[elemento] for elemento in contador if contador[elemento] > 1]
```

Lo anterior te dejaría con una lista de valores enteros donde cada valor entero hace referencia a la sumatoria de todos los repetidos de un elemento, en este caso el único valor repetido es 2 y solo tiene 2 aparaciones por lo cual el valor de lal lista `repetidos` es `[2*2]` es decir `[4]`.

**Solución al problema 2.**

En el anterior paso obtuvimos una lista con los valores repetidos, en este caso solo tenemos un valor repetido pero si existieran más elementos repetidos la anterior lista seria de una dimensión mayor. Para obtener finalmente el resultado esperado es necesario sumar esta lista de valores, para esto python tiene la función `sum` que toma un iterable como argumento y retorna la sumatoria de sus valores

```py
resultado = sum(repetidos)
```

Al final la variable `resultado` contendría el valor esperado sin embargo existen algunas otras formas de llegar al mismo resultado, está posiblemente es una de las que mejor aprovechan las virtudes de python. Una forma un poco más simplista sería ordenar la lista y sumar aquellos valores consecutivos que sean iguales.

Comment: Tengo una pregunta, en "repetidos = [elemento*contador[elemento] for elemento in contador if contador[elemento] > 1]"
El "elemento", te refieres a cada elemento dentro de la lista verdad?.
También Muchas gracias por la explicación tan detallada

Comment: No exactamente, tal vez la forma más correcta de expresarlo sería como el elemento del contador. Recuerda que el contador tiene todos los elementos **únicos** de la lista junto con un contador de cuantas veces se repitio. En este caso la única diferencia seria que contador no tiene 2 veces el elemento 2, solo lo  tiene una vez pero lleva un conteo de que se repitió dos veces.

Comment: Si te sientes incomodo con la sintaxis de list compression te recomendaria que lo empezarás a leer desde el for..... Es decir, ```for elemento in contador```(Para cada elemento en contador), ```if contador[elemento] > 1```(Si el contador de veces que se repitio ese elemento es mayor a 1), entonces ```elemento*contador[elemento]```(Si se cumplio la condición anterior entonces agrega en el vector el resultado de elemento*contador[elemento] que es el elemento multiplicado por el número de veces que se repitió).

Comment: vale okei okei, ahora lo entiendo!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación tan detallada!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes validar si el número se encuentra en la lista y sumarlo, en este ejemplo se muestra los valores sin la repetición, los valores que se repiten y la suma de los valores repetidos:

```
#/usr/bin/python3
values = [1,2,2,3,3,3,1,2,3,5,6,5,6,7,13]
repeat = []
unique = []
resultSum = 0

for i in values :
    if i not in unique:
        unique.append(i)
    else:
        resultSum += i
        if i not in repeat:
            repeat.append(i)

print("Los valores sin repetición son:", unique)
print("Los valores que se repiten son:", repeat)
print("La suma de los valores repetidos es:", resultSum)
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos!

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias, se entiende perfectamente!!